# Having trouble combining two queries (subquery)

Tags: mysql, subquery

So I want to make a query that shows the managers name who have employees with less than two orders. I have two queries:

This one shows employees who have less than two orders

```
Select Employee.EID
FROM Employee, OrderT
WHERE Employee.EID = OrderT.EID
GROUP BY Employee.EID
HAVING COUNT(OrderID) < 2
```

This one shows the manager of each employee

```
SELECT Employee.Name AS Manager 
FROM Employee, Employee M
WHERE Employee.EID = M.ManagerID
GROUP BY Employee.Name
```

I am trying to combine them and make a subquery but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I keep trying different things for the past two hours and can't seem to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh no not misunderstanding, im not limiting the result. I need to get people who have less than two orders and from there figure out who's their manager

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add manager id to first query since the manager field is in the employee table.

```
Select Employee.EID, Employee.ManagerID
FROM Employee, OrderT
WHERE Employee.EID = OrderT.EID
GROUP BY Employee.EID
HAVING COUNT(OrderID) < 2
```

Comment: Yes, this does show employeeID and ManagerID, however, I just want to get the name of the manager, not id nor employeeID